# 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named UIStoryboardPresentationSegueTemplate'

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xcode6

I'm re editing the code of an app to design in xcode 5 for improve it and make it compatible with ios8 and change the view of the storyboard to "use size classes" for the same interface to display vien both iPhone and iPad I work all well in ios 8, but when trying to compile it into 7.x ios devices generates me this error:

```
'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named UIStoryboardPresentationSegueTemplate'
```

now does not work for ios versions prior to 8 someone has any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the view controller inside storyboard under File Inspector and change the field "**Build for**" from "**iOS8 and later**" to the desired version.

Comment: Thanks thats work perfect but now don`t works on ios 8 :S